# error SQL STATE 42P01

Tags: postgresql

I have to take data from 4 different tables and insert them in a fifth table.

```
insert into leggeapprovata (titolo, 
         relatore,
         numerolegislatura,
         testo,
         votisi,
         votino,
         astenuti,
         datapromulgazione,
         promulgatada,
         numlegge,
         dataapprovazionecamera,
         dataapprovazionesenato) 
values ('[Legge di bilancio 2018] Bilancio di previsione dello Stato per l anno finanziario 2018 e bilancio pluriennale per il triennio 2018-2020',
'{"Marcello Gualdani","Magda Angela Zanoni","Pier Carlo Padoan"}',
'17',
'https://parlamento17.openpolis.it/atto/documento/id/523404',
'140',
'94',
'0',
'2017-12-23',
'Sergio Mattarella',
'S.2960-B  ',
'2017-12-22',
'2017-12-23');
```

OUTPUT:

> ERRORE:  elemento FROM per la tabella "ddl" mancante LINE 13:
>   VALUES (ddl.titolo,

```
                   ^
```

QUERY:

```
insert into leggeapprovata (titolo, 
         relatore,
         numerolegislatura,
         testo,
         votisi,
         votino,
         astenuti,
         datapromulgazione,
         promulgatada,
         numlegge,
         dataapprovazionecamera,
         dataapprovazionesenato) 
      VALUES (ddl.titolo, 
         ddl.relatore,
         legislatura.numero,
         ddl.testo,
         votazione.favorevoli,
         votazione.contrari,
         votazione.astenuti,
         promulgazione.data,
         promulgazione.presidente,
         votazione.codice,
         votazione.data,
         votazione.data)
```

> CONTEXT:  funzione PL/pgSQL inserimentoinleggeapprovata() riga 9 a
>   istruzione SQL
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERRORE: elemento FROM per la tabella "ddl" mancante SQL state: 42P01
>   Context: funzione PL/pgSQL inserimentoinleggeapprovata() riga 9 a

Istruzione SQL

```
begin
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ddl
WHERE NEW.titolo = ddl.titolo AND ddl.promulgato ='si')
-- AND 
--IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM promulgazione WHERE
 --  NEW.titolo =promulgazione.ddl) 
--AND IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM votazione WHERE NEW.titolo=votazione.ddl) 
   then 
      insert into leggeapprovata (titolo, 
         relatore,
         numerolegislatura,
         testo,
         votisi,
         votino,
         astenuti,
         datapromulgazione,
         promulgatada,
         numlegge,
         dataapprovazionecamera,
         dataapprovazionesenato) 
      VALUES (ddl.titolo, 
         ddl.relatore,
         legislatura.numero,
         ddl.testo,
         votazione.favorevoli,
         votazione.contrari,
         votazione.astenuti,
         promulgazione.data,
         promulgazione.presidente,
         votazione.codice,
         votazione.data,
         votazione.data);
   end if;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM votazione WHERE NEW.titolo =votazione.ddl and votazione.tipoassemblea='camera')
   then
      insert into leggeapprovata (dataapprovazionecamera) 
      values (votazione.data);
   elsif EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM votazione WHERE NEW.titolo =votazione.ddl and votazione.tipoassemblea='senato')
   then
      insert into leggeapprovata (dataapprovazionesenato) 
      values (votazione.data);
   end if;

 return new;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.inserimentoinleggeapprovata TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.inserimentoinleggeapprovata TO public;
end;


CREATE TRIGGER inserimentoinleggeapprovata
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON public.leggeapprovata
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.inserimentoinleggeapprovata();




CREATE TABLE public.leggeapprovata
(
  titolo character varying(500) NOT NULL,
  numerolegislatura integer NOT NULL,
  testo text,
  votisi integer,
  votino integer,
  astenuti integer,
  datapromulgazione date,
  promulgatada character varying(100),
  relatore character varying(100)[] NOT NULL,
  dataapprovazionecamera date,
  dataapprovazionesenato date,
  numlegge character(10),
  CONSTRAINT leggeapprovatapkey PRIMARY KEY (titolo, numerolegislatura, relatore),
  CONSTRAINT leggeapprovatanumerolegislaturafkey FOREIGN KEY (numerolegislatura)
      REFERENCES public.legislatura (numero) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT leggeapprovatapromulgatadafkey FOREIGN KEY (promulgatada)
      REFERENCES public.presidentedellarepubblica (presidente) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT leggeapprovatatestofkey FOREIGN KEY (testo, relatore)
      REFERENCES public.ddl (testo, relatore) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT leggeapprovatatitolofkey FOREIGN KEY (titolo, datapromulgazione)
      REFERENCES public.promulgazione (ddl, data) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT leggeapprovatavotisifkey FOREIGN KEY (votisi, votino, astenuti, numlegge)
      REFERENCES public.votazione (favorevoli, contrari, astenuti, codice) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT leggeapprovatatitolonumerolegislaturatestorelatorenukey UNIQUE (titolo, numerolegislatura, testo, relatore, numlegge)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.leggeapprovata
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.leggeapprovata TO public;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.leggeapprovata TO postgres WITH GRANT OPTION;

-- Trigger: inserimentoinleggeapprovata on public.leggeapprovata

-- DROP TRIGGER inserimentoinleggeapprovata ON public.leggeapprovata;

CREATE TRIGGER inserimentoinleggeapprovata
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON public.leggeapprovata
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.inserimentoinleggeapprovata();
```

Comment: Please have a look at this topics: [How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) and [How to use markdown to format questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Comment: is not really a duplicate, the query is the same, the error is the same, but I had modified the function of the trigger with the suggestion given to me by the programmer, and the result gives me the same error.